# Have I narrowed this question sufficiently?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked a question which was put on hold because

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
>   or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087402/what-are-the-most-probable-causes-of-small-css-changes-mis-renderings-in-chrom

I have attempted to rewrite it so that there is a single definitive answer. Please could you look and tell me whether I've achieved that? If not, please could you suggest how I could? Or ask me questions that might help me to?

I suspect that someone in the community has the knowledge to help with this, and that this is a common enough issue that other developers will benefit too. I just need to find a way to shape the question to make it appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 4):

The question is still way too broad.  There is by no means a single objectively correct answer.

If anything your edits have simply make the question more opinion based, while still leaving it extremely broad.

An appropriate SO question would have the code to reproduce the problem in a well defined manner for any reader along with specific criteria for how the program ought to behave.

Comment: thanks. I am not able to reproduce the issue (only the user can, intermittently), so if "hav[ing] the code to reproduce the problem" is a hard criteria for a SO questions then I guess this is an issue where SO cannot help. Can you think of a way I can restructure the question to make it compatible with SO? I suspect someone in the community has the knowledge to help, but I understand that alone is not sufficient for it to be a SO question - it also needs to follow other rules. Any way we can make that so?

Comment: @tom Fundamentally here there is a specific problem, and to get help resolving that problem you'd need to provide enough information to replicate the problem.  There's no real way around it that I see.

Comment: I accept that there is no way to get SO to help with the specific problem, because I cannot provide enough information on how to recreate it. So instead I'm trying to ask a question separate from the specific case, asking *in general*, what can cause CSS to be slightly changed in Chrome. (i.e. I'm not asking for an autopsy on a specific patient, I'm asking for aggregate cause-of-death statistics). I'm struggling to understand why that is not a question fit for SO. Wouldn't all web developers benefit from knowing about issues that cause their users to see html differently to themselves?

Comment: @tom That question isn't appropriate because it's too broad, as the close reason is telling you.

Comment: sorry to keep going on, but it specifically says "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format". It doesnt seem that there would be too many answers, as I'm specifically asking 'what are the *most probable* causes', to which there is a single definitive answer (assuming someone has gathered the data, otherwise there are zero answers). It doesnt seem the answer would be too long, as each cause could be described in a single line. e.g. http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/leading-causes-of-death.htm Sorry to be a pain, but I dont get it.

Comment: @tom Again, I refer you to my answer.  If you're looking for a *single* response (your question doesn't, but even if you did) that just makes it primarily opinion based, as you just get everyone posting their opinion of what they think the most likely is.  It in no way solves the problem, as there simply is no way to objectively state what the correct answer is.

Comment: OK, I think I'm starting to see. You suspect that there would be many answers where people just guess the most likely cause (which clearly is subjective, and not useful), *and* that there would be zero answers where someone lists the 5 most probable causes, backed up with data on their relative likelihood, citing sources. You might be right about that, but it seems a shame to pre-judge that. There was probably a time in the Middle Ages when people believed that no-one could objectively answer the 'cause of death' question, but we got there eventually, by trying..

Comment: turns out a comment on the original question helped me figure out what the particular issue is. I realize that still doesn't make it a suitable question for SO, but it just seems a shame to me that developers in the future wont have access to this information. Even though it required some guess work, the system did work here - my question was enough for another user to graciously make a guess, and that solved the issue. Is there really no way at all that we can mould this information to fit SO, so that other developers can benefit?

Comment: @tom Sure there is, you can provide enough information in the quesiton for the answer to be the single objectively correct answer, and not a guess.

Comment: at the time I asked the question, I didnt have any more information - I provided everything I had. A different developer with the same problem would similarly have little information, and would be searching on Google or SO accordingly. So for it to be helpful, it would have to limit itself to the information at hand. Can you suggest a wording that would work for SO and users in that regard?

Comment: @tom Another user with the information at hand could easily have actually had one of *tens of thousands* of other problems.  Either the question would need to have all of those solutions (which simply isn't practical, as that's too broad) or it would only have an answer for a tiny fraction of the people with that same question, because the answer to the question is nowhere near providing a complete answer to the actual question asked.  This is why such questions don't belong here.

Comment: yes, that is true. If you take that long list of possible causes, and rank them by prior probability then the problem you describe is significantly reduced. And you then have a resource that is probably the most useful thing a developer could have in that situation. But if you say it nonetheless does not clear the bar for absolute usefulness on SO then I'll defer to your judgement on that. Still seems a shame. Thanks for taking time to discuss this.